# Testing images directly rather than web pages in PhantomCSS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, phantomcss, resemblejs

The demonstrations of PhantomCSS commonly use web pages in test. Is there a way to test images instead?

Comment: You mean compare images? Yes, it seems you can do this with resemblejs and you don't need PhantomJS for that.

Comment: @ArtjomB. resemblejs actually uses phantomJS, the old one too...

Comment: No, resemblejs has no dependency on PhantomJS. It is a pure JavaScript library which also works in Node.js. It's PhantomCSS that has a dependency on PhantomJS.

Comment: Yes, I know resemble.js can handle images directly, but I like some feature that PhantomCSS has (which uses resemble.js internally.) I am interested in using the resemble.js image-power directly in PhantomCSS or some other means to use images directly in PhantomCSS